# When i use php setrawcookie function getting server error

Tags: php, nginx, php-5.6

I am facing strange issue, When I use setrawcookie function, I got error 502,

```
setrawcookie("PVEAuthCookie", $vncproxy['ticket'], 0, "/",'mydomain.com', true);
```

It's throw me 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.11.5 error.

I have PHP Version 5.6.40, 
Cookie settings, [image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Check your PHP error log.

Comment: Why setrawcookie, why not setcookie? Does it work with setcookie? What is the value you're setting?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, It was from nginx

> 41014 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream,

I update proxy buffering configuration and its works,

> proxy_buffer_size   128k;
>    proxy_buffers   4 256k;
>   proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

Thanks @Barmar